# Can't initialize model with a serialized field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, serialization

I've recently added a 'preferences' field for my users which uses thw ActiveRecord serialize method in my rails app. This works fine for existing users but when I try initializing a new user model in the console I get an error:

```
u = User.new
#=> 
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: preferences was supposed to be a Hash, but was a String
```

I've added the field like this in the migration:

```
add_column :users, :preferences, :text, :default => { :allows_public_contributions => false }.to_yaml
```

And in the model, user.rb:

```
serialize :preferences, Hash
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have callbacks on your User model? Like a before_create or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails handles the serialization by itself. Remove the `to_yaml` method call from the default option in your migration. If you run this method on a hash you get a string.

```
{ :key => "value" } 
# => "---\n:key: value\n"
```

That is the reason why you get the exception.